# Neural networks physical model

Tags: machine-learning

Is neural network=Tree data structure?.If not how neural networks r described using physical model?

For ex:An array is considered as collection of similar data under same name(sequential memory allocation=physical model)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  You seem to need more research on your own before you're ready to ask a question here.

Answer (score 1):

A neural network is not a data structure, but rather a tool used in machine learning to create artificial neural networks, which are an oversimplification of how we think that the human brain works.

You can use arrays to construct your network, but these will just be a component in a much larger piece.

For instance, in a neural network, one neuron from a given layer, is connected to one or more neurons from its adjacent layers. These connections, in turn, have weights. These weighted connections can be described by an array.

Another way in which arrays can be used in neural networks is when it comes to its inputs. Neural networks tend to take vectors as input, which can be described using arrays., for instance, if you have a neural network which operates with numbers, you can transform your number into binary and then store that binary number in an array, for instance, the number `8` could be transformed as `[0, 0, 0, 1, 0]`.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between the two is, Tree is a data structure, and Neural Network is a learning algorithm. Tree has one root and several leaves. There is no such structure in Neural Network. You may feel by the looks of it that they are similar, but it's not. Trees can store data, hence their type - data structure. But neural network doesn't; it is a function which takes input, applies some weights and biases to work on the input to find the input's closeness to the possible or expected output(s).